# Dynamic Linq Contains to filter a List

Tags: c#, linq, oop, generics, dynamic

I have this Method

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Filter<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, string searchStr)
{
    var propsToCheck = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(a => a.PropertyType == typeof(string));

    var filter = propsToCheck.Aggregate(string.Empty, (s, p) => (s == string.Empty ? string.Empty : string.Format("{0} OR ", s)) + string.Format("{0} == @0", p.Name).ToLower());

    var filtered = source.AsQueryable().Where(filter, searchStr);
    return filtered;
}
```

Which takes List and a search string and finds any matches in the list. However this only works for 100% matches, how can I make this case insensitive and use contains instead of a 100% match ?

Comment: So basically you need to filter only those strings that contain the given string?

Comment: No, lets say I pass a List of Objects, one property is countries and has value Australia and Austria. So when I send the method with Search string, "Aus" it returns back the list with both countries in it. It is to search inside a list, go through all fields and return objects where any property contains the given string. Also I need it to be case insensitive

Comment: And it should work for objects of any type? (BTW you can't do typeof(T) in generic functions. Or the code from your question actually works like this?)

Comment: Yeah basically I want to create a method, where I pass in a list of objects and a search string, it dynamically figures out the properties of the object and sends back a list of objects which contain the string. This is a generic method that can take a list of any object. Also some properties of objects can be null, which is where I am having issues as well

Comment: The code works currently, but only on 100% matches and is case sensitive. I am using Dynamic Linq

Comment: I wouldn't use linq for this, I'll write an answer with a different approach.

Comment: Interesting ! Okay I am curious. Thank you Goran

Comment: It's not clear to me what purpose the `AsQueryable()` call has here.

Comment: @Neon Tapir, this is because its taking a Generic List

Comment: Reading the documentation, maybe this is an overload of `IQueryable` that's offered in dynamic LINQ. In general, though, if you need `List<T>` functionality, then the input parameter's type should change.

Comment: @user3067743 i think for your implementation you simply need use `Contains` instead of `==`, and `searchStr.ToLower()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Constructing a dynamic LINQ query doesn't look like the best option here. Filtering with a delegate would do better:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Filter<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, string searchStr)
{
  var searchStrLower = searchStr.ToLower();
  var propsToCheck = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(a => a.PropertyType == typeof(string) && a.CanRead);

  return source.Where(obj => {
    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in propsToCheck)
    {
      string value = (string)prop.GetValue(obj);
      if (value != null && value.ToLower().Contains(searchStrLower)) return true;
    }
    return false;
  });
}
```

Comment: Very well, thank you sir, I owe you one. Seriously I had been scratching my head on this for a week already. Thank you